# filter array of object which contains array of objects by an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I`m trying to filter an array but I don t succeed to filter array inside the object

I will give us an example of how the array is:

```
const data = [
   {
    path: 'data1',
    main: [
       {
        path: 'mainData11'
       },
       {
        path: 'mainData12'
       }
     ]
   },
   {
    path: 'data2',
    main: [
       {
        path: 'mainData21'
       },
       {
        path: 'mainData22'
       }
     ]
   }
];

const filterArray = ['data1', 'mainData12'];
```

**expected result**

```
const data = [
 {
  path: 'data1'
  main: [
   {
    path: 'mainData12' 
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

**What I`ve tried**

```
data.filter(el => filterArray.includes(el.path))
```

I did not succeed to filter the `main` inside object...

How I do that?

Thanks!

****UPDATE -- CURRENT SOLUTION**

```
data.reduce((results, item) => {
 if(filterArray.some(f => item.path === f)){
  results.push(
   {
    ...item,
    path: item.path,
    main: item.main.filter(i => filterArray.some(f => i.path === f))
   }
  )
 };
 return results;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in one step if you use a reduce

```js
const data = [
   {
    path: 'data1',
    main: [
       {
        path: 'mainData11'
       },
       {
        path: 'mainData12'
       }
     ]
   },
   {
    path: 'data2',
    main: [
       {
        path: 'mainData21'
       },
       {
        path: 'mainData22'
       }
     ]
   }
];

const filterArray = ['data1', 'mainData12'];

const results = data.reduce((results, item) => {
  if (filterArray.some(f => item.path === f) && item.main.some(i => filterArray.some(f => i.path === f))) {
    results.push(
      { path: item.path, main: item.main.filter(i => filterArray.some(f => i.path === f)) }
    );
  }
  return results;
 }, []);

console.log(results)
```

Comment: thanks for awsering. The problem is that the `filterArray` elements position are not fixed. Exemple `data1` can be on positon 3. I must to search in that array if exists

Comment: Edited to search filter array

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by rebuilding the object:

```js
const data = [{
    path: 'data1',
    main: [{
        path: 'mainData11',
      },
      {
        path: 'mainData12',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'data2',
    main: [{
        path: 'mainData21',
      },
      {
        path: 'mainData22',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const filterArray = ['data1', 'mainData12'];

const filteredData = data
  .filter(entry => entry.path === filterArray[0])
  .map(entry => ({
    path: entry.path,
    main: entry.main.filter(x => x.path === filterArray[1]),
  }))
  .filter(entry => entry.main.length);

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: thanks. Yes this is the current solution to rebuild the object.

Comment: A filter followed by a map should be done in a single iteration with a reduce or else you are iterating the collection multiple times.